# Python use list of list as key in dict

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like this:

```
l = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
```

How can I use `l` as a key in a dict? I tried to make a `frozenset` out of `l`:

```
l = frozenset(l)
d[l] = True
```

but I'm getting

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: You could convert it to a tuple: `d[tuple(tuple(_) for _ in l)] = True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

This is because you still have the *inner lists* which are unhashable.

You can do:

```
>>> key = frozenset(map(frozenset, l))
>>> {key: 'test'}
{frozenset([frozenset([5, 6]), frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([3, 4])]): 'test'}
```

Or, make it a `tuple`:

```
>>> key = tuple(map(tuple, l))
>>> {key: 'test'}
{((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)): 'test'}
```